# LightSwitch WebApplication not entering Global.asax file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, global-asax, visual-studio-lightswitch

How can i get my lightswitch application to enter the `global.asax` file?
In the `ServerGenerated` project i've implemented an own login screen for the users. Further more i added the `global.asax` file to the `ServerGenerated` project of the lightswitch application.

The own login screen i've implemented is loading correctly - but it seems that the lightswitch application is ignoring the `global.asax` file.

The methods `Application_Start` and so on are not entered. What am i doing wrong?

PS: The lightswitch application is an web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a simple and stupid solution for this problem: 
The global.asax will be copied into

```
Bin\Debug\bin\ServerGenerated
```

after compilation.

Just copy the file into the root of the debug folder (where the default.htm is placed) and your are able to debug thru the global.asax.